# Passing StateAndRef in nodeshell Start command

Tags: corda

I am trying to start shareAccountInfo from node shell, shareAccountInfo expecting two values acccountInfo and recipients . AccountInfo expects StateAndRef<com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo> type. I am able to pass recipients but it is not accepting accountInfo value

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap this AccountSDK flow in a flow. And in the wrapper flow, you can use AccountID or Account name to query the AccountInfo state.